# javascript for loop through nested json values

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, highcharts

I am trying to loop through a json file for all the `total`  and `first_record` values. The key is

```
json.STATION[0].OBSERVATIONS.precipitation[0].total
```

I'm trying to return a result:

```
[20180116, 0.8], [20180117, 0.0] . . .
```

I've tried a variety of approaches. My best result has been the classic `undefined` 
Below is a snippet from the jsfiddle I have been working on. The json is generated by mesowest.net api.

Once I have this sorted out I am hoping to plot the values in highcharts. thanks.

```js
const data = {
  "UNITS": {
    "precipitation": "Inches"
  },
  "STATION": [{
    "STATUS": "ACTIVE",
    "MNET_ID": "25",
    "PERIOD_OF_RECORD": {
      "start": "20000120",
      "end": "20180121"
    },
    "ELEVATION": "6340",
    "NAME": "BOGUS BASIN",
    "RESTRICTED": false,
    "STID": "BOGI1",
    "ELEV_DEM": "6362",
    "LONGITUDE": "-116.09685",
    "STATE": "ID",
    "OBSERVATIONS": {
      "precipitation": [{
        "count": 23,
        "first_report": "20180115",
        "interval": 1,
        "report_type": "precip_accum",
        "last_report": "20180115",
        "total": 0.0
      }, {
        "count": 24,
        "first_report": "20180116",
        "interval": 2,
        "report_type": "precip_accum",
        "last_report": "20180116",
        "total": 0.2
      }, {
        "count": 24,
        "first_report": "20180117",
        "interval": 3,
        "report_type": "precip_accum",
        "last_report": "20180117",
        "total": 0.0
      }, {
        "count": 24,
        "first_report": "20180118",
        "interval": 4,
        "report_type": "precip_accum",
        "last_report": "20180118",
        "total": 0.0
      }, {
        "count": 24,
        "first_report": "20180119",
        "interval": 5,
        "report_type": "precip_accum",
        "last_report": "20180119",
        "total": 0.8
      }, {
        "count": 24,
        "first_report": "20180120",
        "interval": 6,
        "report_type": "precip_accum",
        "last_report": "20180120",
        "total": 0.0
      }, {
        "count": 13,
        "first_report": "20180121",
        "interval": 7,
        "report_type": "precip_accum",
        "last_report": "20180121",
        "total": 0.0
      }]
    },
    "LATITUDE": "43.76377",
    "TIMEZONE": "America\/Boise",
    "ID": "1160"
  }],
  "SUMMARY": {
    "DATA_QUERY_TIME": 1.6429424286,
    "RESPONSE_CODE": 1,
    "RESPONSE_MESSAGE": "OK",
    "METADATA_RESPONSE_TIME": "0.0920295715332 ms",
    "NUMBER_OF_OBJECTS": 1,
    "PRECIP_DATA_TIME": 2.4950504303,
    "DATA_PARSE_TIME": 0.8418560028
  }
};

   
console.log(data.STATION[0].OBSERVATIONS.precipitation[4].total);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data.STATION[0].OBSERVATIONS.precipitation[4].total;

const totl = data.STATION[0].OBSERVATIONS.precipitation[0].total;
console.log(totl);
// 

var i, precipitation;
for (i = 0; i < data.STATION[0].OBSERVATIONS.precipitation.total.length; i++) {
  precip = data.STATION[0].OBSERVATIONS.precipitation[i].total;
}
console.log(precip);
//console.log(obj);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: @Black.Jack there is no recursion needed here. That link has no relevance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, in your `for` loop you are referring to `data.STATION[0].OBSERVATIONS.precipitation.total.length`, but the `total` part isn't even defined there. It's have to be `precipitation[0].total` for it to be anything, and even then, it isn't an array. You just want:

```
data.STATION[0].OBSERVATIONS.precipitation.length
```

Also, just code-style wise, stick that into a variable so you don't have to type that craziness over and over. It'll also help avoid typos:

```
const records = data.STATION[0].OBSERVATIONS.precipitation;
```

You also are just setting the same value back to a variable over and over, so at the end, you'd only have the last value. You want to stick them in an array.

```
const totals = [];
for (let i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
  totals.push(records[i].total);
}
```

If you want both `total` and `first_report`, you can either do parallel arrays:

```
const totals = [];
const firsts = [];
for (let i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
  totals.push(records[i].total);
  firsts.push(records[i].first_record);
}
```

or have an array of arrays:

```
const results = [];
for (let i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
  results.push([records[i].total, records[i].first_record]);
}
```

Here is a working example:

```js
const data = {
  "UNITS": {
    "precipitation": "Inches"
  },
  "STATION": [{
    "STATUS": "ACTIVE",
    "MNET_ID": "25",
    "PERIOD_OF_RECORD": {
      "start": "20000120",
      "end": "20180121"
    },
    "ELEVATION": "6340",
    "NAME": "BOGUS BASIN",
    "RESTRICTED": false,
    "STID": "BOGI1",
    "ELEV_DEM": "6362",
    "LONGITUDE": "-116.09685",
    "STATE": "ID",
    "OBSERVATIONS": {
      "precipitation": [{
        "count": 23,
        "first_report": "20180115",
        "interval": 1,
        "report_type": "precip_accum",
        "last_report": "20180115",
        "total": 0.0
      }, {
        "count": 24,
        "first_report": "20180116",
        "interval": 2,
        "report_type": "precip_accum",
        "last_report": "20180116",
        "total": 0.2
      }, {
        "count": 24,
        "first_report": "20180117",
        "interval": 3,
        "report_type": "precip_accum",
        "last_report": "20180117",
        "total": 0.0
      }, {
        "count": 24,
        "first_report": "20180118",
        "interval": 4,
        "report_type": "precip_accum",
        "last_report": "20180118",
        "total": 0.0
      }, {
        "count": 24,
        "first_report": "20180119",
        "interval": 5,
        "report_type": "precip_accum",
        "last_report": "20180119",
        "total": 0.8
      }, {
        "count": 24,
        "first_report": "20180120",
        "interval": 6,
        "report_type": "precip_accum",
        "last_report": "20180120",
        "total": 0.0
      }, {
        "count": 13,
        "first_report": "20180121",
        "interval": 7,
        "report_type": "precip_accum",
        "last_report": "20180121",
        "total": 0.0
      }]
    },
    "LATITUDE": "43.76377",
    "TIMEZONE": "America\/Boise",
    "ID": "1160"
  }],
  "SUMMARY": {
    "DATA_QUERY_TIME": 1.6429424286,
    "RESPONSE_CODE": 1,
    "RESPONSE_MESSAGE": "OK",
    "METADATA_RESPONSE_TIME": "0.0920295715332 ms",
    "NUMBER_OF_OBJECTS": 1,
    "PRECIP_DATA_TIME": 2.4950504303,
    "DATA_PARSE_TIME": 0.8418560028
  }
};

const records = data.STATION[0].OBSERVATIONS.precipitation;

const results = [];

for (let i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
  results.push([records[i].total, records[i].first_report]);
}

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, your key is not `precipitation[0]` but you want to iterate through all precipitation elements:

```
// precipitation is an array, so it supports Array.prototype.map()

var output = data.STATION[0].OBSERVATIONS.precipitation.map(function(p) {
    return [p.first_report, p.total] });
```

see also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map